# Removing Label Legend "Other" in a Pie Chart using RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008, rdlc

Is there a way on how to display the original label legend in the pie chart instead of displaying "Other"?

I have a Pie Chart that has 5 Slices each slice has their own data in percent. But I have a problem for some of my data when the last slice which is 5 has 0 data and slices for 1-4 has their data but the Legend displays only the 3 Slice and the 4 & 5 slices display their Legend as "Other".

Please see screenshot below:

[image]
Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the actual pie in the chart to select the chart series. In the properties windows expand Custom Attributes.

[image]

You will probably have this set to 'Single Slice'. If you change this to 'None' the all slices are shown and displayed on the legend.